# How to view Objective-c( assembly code equivalent) at the break point?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, assembly

How to view XCode( assembly code equivalent) at the break point?

I have gone to Thread1 and it shows objective-c for the [ViewController viewDidLoad] and then assembly for [UIViewController view] and [UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible]. I want to be able to see the assembly for [ViewController viewDidLoad] with the marker at the break pt?

(Product->GenerateOutput->Generate Assembly File:  doesn't show the break pts.)

thx

```
void addme(int *a)
{
    *a += 0xFF;// <-- I want to see the assembly for this:  should see an instruction "ADD" in the assembly break down
    *a += 1;
    *a += 2;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    int a = 12;
    addme(&a);
}
```

Comment: If you cant find the exact place you want with any asm debugger, then place there random code which will be easy to find. If you cant find the place you want with debugger I cant get why you are trying to do that? Maybe I don't understand your point.

Comment: What are you using for assembly code view?

Comment: I added that code I want to see the assembly for

Comment: stop at your breakpoint, then in gdb: `disass *$pc`

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. Put breakpoint where you want to see the assembly code
2. Run program
3. Once program pauses hit the button that looks like ->| (but pointing down)
4. Repeat step 3 a lot
5. Dance
6. See the world
7. Wonder at the joys of life
8. Pop bottles
9. Grow old
10. Die

I'm not quite sure this is what you're asking for, but I just did it (well, steps 1-5 & 8) and it worked for me.

[image]

It's at the bottom of the screen, above the console.

Comment: where is the key you are suggesting:  ->|   

is it the key about the [enter] key? do I hold down the [command] key?  thx

Comment: I don't know anything about assembly so I don't really know what I'm looking at. You might want to talk to @loler.

Comment: I just looked and maybe if you put it in something that calls `viewDidLoad` and then step through the code until you hit the call, you'll see it. Again, no idea what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

And it's also likely that you won't see an assembly ADD instruction at all, since compile time constants are calculated and thus optimized away by the compiler at compile time.

Comment: I removed the constant and put the code in a function.  Posted code above

Answer (score 0):

@jdl At the matter of fact i don't know Objective-C and @Dustin doesn't know asm... As i understood `viewDidLoad` function will execute a code in it when some object is loaded. In my opinion you can compile only that part of code which you included in your question and look into assembly code via `IDA pro` for Mac OS or some other debugger.